# How do you overcome the boredom (and loneliness) of Forex day trading?

Tags: trading, stock-markets, foreign-exchange, stock-exchanges, day-trading

I have two trading plans which I use to day trade in the Forex market for 2 hours a day (8-10 am UK time). Usually I will have between 2-4 valid trading signals each day. I have made more than 80 trades for each plan and find that both of them are profitable. I have set up an alert system so I do not need to glue my eyes to the chart for the full 2 hours when trading. However, on some days I find myself getting so bored. For example, yesterday (Friday) I have 2 trading signals in 2 hours, and both happen to be break even (which means I only lose the spread, around 2 pips). When I am bored, I feel an urge to take on more trades outside of my plans which is an extremely stupid thing to do. I get envious of my friends who work in an office, where they have colleagues to take to and go to lunch with. Having such human connection makes them less lonely and bored. But for me, day trading is a solo activity and I feel that I lose out on the human connection. How do you deal with boredom and loneliness in day trading?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't really about personal finance.

Comment: Find a different line of work!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion jamesqf. I am trading part time, I have another job as an independent researcher. I took up trading just to get more income.